# CSS background-position calculated from left? I want it RIGHT

Tags: css, background-position

I need to allocate some background image to a certain div, the thing is it needs to be positioned from right and not the usual left in CSS. So when defining `background-position`, it can read, say , right, or some big percentage (which is also calculated from the left side of the screen but anyway works) and.. that's it. I cannot use pixels and get it to go with a fix distance from the right side of its container. Am I right here? So, is there a work-around for this? Anything to do with LESS if that helps? Theoretically, I can have it set to right and somehow decrease a couple of pixels then.

We have margin-right:+-px, padding-right:+px, but not background-position-right:+-px ?

Comment: Can't understand the down voting

Comment: If you know before hand the dimensions of the div and the image, you can calculate a percentage that does that. see here:  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15044753/1926369]. the big percentage is not calculated from the left side !!! (neither from the right, it doesn't help much for your purposes, anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background-position: right 20px;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position

JSBIN example: http://jsbin.com/ixejey/1/

UPDATE:

Oops, I may have misunderstood the question. The above positions the background image to the right side and 20px from the top--but not a set distance away from the right side. I don't think you can do that at this time with CSS alone.

For now what you could do is instead of using a background image on the element directly, wrap the element inside a wrapper div, then add a second div to hold the "background" image and position it absolutely--which you can do from the right a specific distance.

Example of the alternative option:

```
<div id="yourContainer">
    <div id="yourBackGroundImage"></div>
    <div id="yourContent">your content</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#yourContainer {
    position: relative;
}

#yourBackGroundImage {
    width: 100;
    height: 100;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: ... but that's not my answer probably, DA. By changing that 20px, your example is changing the image's vertical positioning rather than the horizontal left<>right one.

Comment: Yeah I now see, but I couldn't get it. Would you give me a CSS pattern of what you mean?

Comment: "I don't think you can do that at this time with CSS alone." You can, but 1) you must set more than 2 values so `right 20px` is considered the x offset, and 2) Chrome does not support this technique anyway, while all other browsers do.

Comment: You mean as Wilson Biggs
 has also said? Would you explain more on that? Maybe in an answer...?

Answer (score 3):

The first value **(calc(100% - 0%))** is the horizontal position and the second value **(calc(100% - 10%))** is the vertical. The top left corner is 0% 0%. The right bottom corner is 100% 100%. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. . Default value is: 0% 0%

```
<div id="hero-content"></div>
```

CSS

```
#hero-content{
  background-position: 
    calc(100% - 0%) /* 0px from the right */
    calc(100% - 10%) /* 10% from the bottom */  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want that in pixels, i.e. calc(100% - 10px). Does it work?

Comment: @EdelAli No it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

and

```
#b {
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: ; //put background style here
}
```

Comment: There was this comment to DA.'s answer by BoltClock. "you must set more than 2 values so right 20px is considered the x offset". Do you also mean that? I'm not getting it anyway but I would try...